# Update UITableView Data from server - did not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

I am struggling with `UITableView`'s data fetching and/or `reloadData()` from server. I am creating this app to check user's pronunciation via server. The data parsing came out well (I checked with print statement) but it won't update to my table cell.

I created a dictionary to store loaded Data:

```
var summaryDict = ["Overall Score" : "Score", "Words" : "Score", "Syllables": "Score", "Phonemes": "Score"]
var summaryArray = ["Overall Score", "Words", "Syllables", "Phonemes"]
```

I did also update dict values after parsing JSON data:

```
.responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    do{
                        let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                        if let data = response.data {
                            if let summaryData = self.parseJSON(data) {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    print(summaryData)
                                    self.summaryDict["Overall Score"] = summaryData.summaryScore
                                    self.summaryDict["Words"] = summaryData.wordScore
                                    self.summaryDict["Syllables"] = summaryData.syllableScore
                                    self.summaryDict["Phonemes"] = summaryData.phoneScore
                                    print(self.summaryDict)
                                    self.delegate?.didUpdateScore(self, score: summaryData)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        let statusJson = json["status"].string
                        if statusJson == "success" {
                            completion("success")
                        }
                        else { completion("error parseJSON") }
                    }   catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("error:\(encodingError)")
                }
        }
```

Over my ViewController I did also added tableview datasource extension:

```
extension FreeTrialViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return audioSender.summaryDict.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as! SummaryCell
        cell.summaryLabel.text = self.audioSender.summaryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.summaryScore.text = self.audioSender.summaryDict[self.audioSender.summaryArray[indexPath.row]]
        
        return cell
        }
    }
```

I tried to put `reloadData()` everywhere I can or `DispatchQueue.main.async` every now and then yet the cell did not update.

EDITED: Include delegate at view controller:

```
extension FreeTrialViewController: AudioSenderDelegate {
    func didFailWithError(_ error: Error) {
        print("parsing audio delegate error: \(error)")
    }
    
    func didUpdateScore(_ audioSender: AudioSender, score: SummaryData) {
//        updateTable()
        summaryTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here's the end result after multiple tries:
(when I took the picture I mistakenly deleted 1 char from the "Overall Score" from the array so the Overall Score disappeared but when I corrected it it goes for 4 "Score".
What I want in the table:

```
Overall Score: 97
Words: 96.8
Syllable: 96.9
Phonemes: 97.0
```

What really showed up:
[image: end result]

EDITED:

I shall include here the func that I call out the table:
Pretty sure inside the `finish recording` is the parse data.
I did try adding the `guard` as:
`guard audioSender.summaryDict["Words"] != "Score" else { return }`
Yet it would come out blank.

[image: table pop up]

Comment: Have you tried after updating dictionary values after parsing JSON Data reload table view data?

Comment: Yes I updated the dict after getting the data, like what I included in the 1st screenshot:

Comment: After updating data you need to reload Table with updated data.

Comment: I did put the `reloadData()` func at my delegate but it's not working. I put it directly inside the parse data yet still not working. Where should it put it? :(

Comment: Where is func responseJSON  in your ViewController or not. I saw func didUpdateScore sent to new "summaryDict" but before reload tableview, you not update data

Comment: @SonPham no, `responseJSON` is in AudioSender while `didUpdateScore` is delegated to the ViewController. You may see the Data Source extension of the VC where I put an `audioSender` as a delegate of the AudioSender. I added a print statement at every step but it seems the table loads up BEFORE the data got in. After the data is parsed I did leave a `reloadData()` at the delegate and every where I can yet no update. Just need to know where should I put that or what should I include else?

Comment: @HàKiềuAnh, in this method `func didUpdateScore(_ audioSender: AudioSender, score: SummaryData)` are you able to get data or print summary data and check method is called or not

Comment: @KishanBhatiya many thanks. Turns out I accidentally deleted my `audioSender.delegate = self` line... it works now. Thanks to adding print statement to the delegate did I find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I forgot to add the line:

```
audioSender.delegate = self
```

so the data won't reload.

Thanks so much for all of your help.
Such a shame on me :).